# kerberos.GSSError: SSPI: InitializeSecurityContext: The specified target is unknown or unreachable

Tags: python, kerberos

C:\Dropbox\gittools\JsonLearning>Auth.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Dropbox\gittools\JsonLearning\Auth.py", line 31, in

```
krb = KerberosTicket("HTTP@xyz.abc.com")
```

File "C:\Dropbox\gittools\JsonLearning\Auth.py", line 9, in **init**

```
kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, "")
```

winkerberos.GSSError: SSPI: InitializeSecurityContext: The specified target is unknown or unreachable

Answer (score 3):

SSPI does not understand GSS-API-style SPNs. Use `HTTP/xyz.abc.com`. This will work.