# InitializeSecurityContext: The specified target is unknown or unreachable

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap, kerberos

Overall goal: I'm trying to authenticate to Active Directory over LDAP with Kerberos on Windows.  Due to dependencies, I'm unable to use `python-ldap` or `python-gssapi`, so I'm using `ldap3` with the [patch found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279503/passwordless-python-ldap3-authentication-from-windows-client/52280673#answer-52280673) to use Kerberos (by way of `winkerberos` instead of `python-gssapi`).

Example code:

```
from ldap3 import Connection, Server, ALL, IP_V4_PREFERRED, SASL, GSSAPI

domain_controller = input("DC: ")

SERVER = Server(domain_controller,
                allowed_referral_hosts=[('*', True)],
                get_info=ALL,
                mode=IP_V4_PREFERRED)

CONNECTION = {"authentication": SASL,
              "sasl_mechanism": GSSAPI,
              "check_names": True}

c = Connection(SERVER, **CONNECTION)
c.bind()
```

Throws:

```
  File "ldap3\core\connection.py", line 550, in bind
    response = self.do_sasl_bind(controls)
  File "ldap3\core\connection.py", line 1252, in do_sasl_bind
    result = sasl_gssapi(self, controls)
  File "ldap3\protocol\sasl\kerberos.py", line 54, in sasl_gssapi
    base64.b64encode(in_token).decode('ascii')
winkerberos.GSSError: SSPI: InitializeSecurityContext: The specified target is unknown or unreachable
```

I've tried changing `@` to `/` from the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520254/kerberos-gsserror-sspi-initializesecuritycontext-the-specified-target-is-unkn#answer-48525379) without any difference.  The socket is resolving the dc fqdn properly, the dc has the SASL/GSSAPI mechanism supported, and I can alternatively pass a username/password to bind successfully.  The part failing here sounds kerberos-specific.

Question: what is causing this error and how can I remediate it?

Comment: Have you tried capturing what is happening with WireShark?

Comment: @Jason Unforunately I don't have privileges/access to do so.

Comment: For future readers: I ended up wrapping a powershell module with python to accomplish my goal, but I was unable to resolve this krb problem natively.